# How place a Vstack container in center of Zstack container?

Tags: swiftui

I want to align the two buttons on the bottom of my Text. How can I align an H-stack
container on bottom of a view ??

```
ZStack{
            VStack{
        Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
        Text("TAP TO SEE MORE")
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .bold()

        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50, content: {
            
            Button("Admin"){

            }

            Button("Employee"){

            }
            
            
        })

        
    
        }
    }
```

[image]

I want to have this content in the middle of screen

Comment: Do you need the ZStack at all? Are you using it for anything else?

Comment: Also… the `Color.white` Is causing your problems. Remove it (or move it to the ZStack (out of the VStack) and it should fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Fogmeister !! Moving Color to the z stack fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
ZStack{
    Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack{

    Text("TAP TO SEE MORE")
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .font(.system(size: 30))
        .bold()

    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50, content: {
        
        Button("Admin"){

        }

        Button("Employee"){

        }
        
        
    })

    

    }
}
```

This should fix it.
The problem was that you had `Color.white.ingoresSafeArea()` inside the VStack, which was placing it above the text and buttons instead of behind, which caused the text etc. to be pushed to the bottom.

Comment: Would recommend cleaning up whitespace in code block

Answer (score 0):

You have to move `Color` inside the `ZStack` instead of `VStack`:

```swift
ZStack {
    Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea() // <-- here
    VStack{
        Text("TAP TO SEE MORE")
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .bold()

        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50) {
            Button("Admin") { }
            Button("Employee") { }
        }
    }
}
```